# How to find matches in text from bag of words and replace to value?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I try to replace words in a text to values from a bag of words. I tried different ways but nothing work. I saw a lot of similar topics on this site but nothing can help.

I have two DataFrames:

## bag_of_words:

```
    word    frequency   probability

0   I       678999      -2.862037

1   like    358754      -3.500018

2   python  341503      -3.549299

3   and     294807      -3.696334

4   pandas  275915      -3.762562
```

## DF:

```
    text

0   I like python

1   and pandas
```

I need to find matches in DF and replace to values to words from bag_of_words:

```
    text

0   -2.862037 -3.500018 -3.549299   

1   -3.696334 -3.76256
```

I tried to resolve in two ways:

```
for word, probability in bag_of_words.itertuples(index=False,name=None):
   df.text = df.text.str.replace(r'\b{0}\b'.format(word),probability)
```

receive an error:

```
  ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

and another way:

```
def correct(w,bag_of_words):
    c =bag_of_words.get(w)
    return c if c else w

def corrections(sent,bag_of_words):
    return " ".join((correct(w, bag_of_words) for w in sent.split()))

df.apply(lambda x: corrections(x.text, bag_of_words),axis=1)
```

receive an error:
#

> ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 0')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested list comprehension with `get` for map values of dictionary:

```
d = bag_of_words.set_index('word')['probability'].to_dict()
DF['text'] = [' '.join(str(d.get(y, y)) for y in x.split()) for x in DF['text']]

print (DF)
                            text
0  -2.862037 -3.500018 -3.549299
1  -3.696334 -3.7625620000000004
```